# AngularJS - Search result matching multiple keywords

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a dashboard which has a table displaying a big amount of projects. It currently has a simple search function which allows me to search for everything that matches that word, using an `ng-model="projectSearch"`. This ng-model is on its own inserted into my `ng-repeat="project in projects.data | filter : projectSearch"`

What I want to implement now is a search function which displays everything that matches one, two or any amount of keywords. I generally found questions about a search function displaying matching 'keyword a' **OR** 'keyword b'.

I want to search for all projects matching 'keyword a' **AND** 'keyword b' etc., being split by for example a space or comma.

My table consists of several fields:

```
<thead>
    <tr md-row style="background-color:rgba(40,53,147,0.5)">
            <th md-column md-order-by="title"><span>Project Name</span></th>
            <th md-column>ID</th>
            <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="total_cpi[total_cpi.length-1].cpi">
                <span>Status</span></th>
            <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="phase"><span>Phase</span></th>
            <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="budget_indication">
                <span>Budget</span></th>
            <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="users[0].user_name"><span>Project Manager</span>
            </th>
            <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="start_date"><span>Start Date</span>
            </th>
            <th md-column md-numeric><span>End Date</span></th>
        </tr>
</thead>
```

My project object looks like:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "project_nr" : 1,
    "title" : "x",
    "start_date_formatted" : "01/01/2016",
    "phase" : "x",
    etc...
}
```

Can I achieve the solution to my problem through a filter?

Comment: Can you give a fiddle of your work ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye My search bar currently works like any regular search bar, such as: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/QL28C/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can do a wildcard search using following:

Create a custom filter-

```
.filter('myfilter', function() {
   return function( items, types) {
    var filtered = [];

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
       if(types.wildcard == false || item.name.match(types.value)) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }

    });

    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Use following in your controller-

```
$scope.projectSearch = "";
var pattern;
    $scope.$watch('projectSearch', function() {
     var pattern = '/^'+ $scope.projectSearch +'*$/'
    });

$scope.types = {value: pattern};
```

With ng-repeat as

```
ng-repeat="project in projects.data | myfilter:types"
```

Let me know if it works.